# Document scanners with NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I need with NativeScript create a camera border object detection and cropping , for documents scanner app. Can you advise me which way?

Comment: For scanning documents (OCR / ML), you could use the [firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase).

Comment: Can explain how can your this plugin for detecting on live camera corners of document (in generally objects) and edit selection these corners. The same you can see on Dropbox, google drive scanner acquisition. Thanks

Comment: May be I miss understood the term scanner, you may be looking for [CameraPlus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus) for taking picture and something like [ImageCropper](https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-imagecropper) for cropping image. I doubt there is any plugin gives you the ability to detect corners of object out of the box, you may use libraries like OpenCV to process the image.